# Checking if empty vs not checking at all

Tags: php

My code is finished and i'm trying to optimize it. I was wondering if the following 2 are the same or am I missing something that could potentially cause problems later on?

```
$this_awardid = !empty($_POST['awardid']) ? $_POST['awardid'] : null;

if (empty($this_awardid) ) {
    ...
} elseif (!empty($this_awardid)) {
    ...
}
```

I've optimized the code like so... I'm assuming that `$this_awardid` it's NOT empty, so there is no need to verify.. Is this logic correct?

```
if (empty($this_awardid) ) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Comment: There are __only two__ values that `empty` returns - __true__ or __false__. So, `elseif` is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `$this_awardid` right there. It's guaranteed to exist. There's no need to use `empty` for it at all, since all `empty` does is suppress error messages for non-existing variables. You *want* error messages should you find `$this_awardid` to be non-existent, since that means something's very wrong with your code.

Secondly, `if (a) else if (!a)` is *always* redundant; you do not need to test for the inverse of the condition again, that is already contained in the `if..else` itself.

So, all you need is:

```
if (!$this_awardid) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`empty` returns **true** or **false**. So no need for `elseif`

```
if (empty($this_awardid) ) {

   // response here

} else {

  // proceed here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$this_awardid = !empty($_POST['awardid']) ? $_POST['awardid'] : null;
```

At this point in your code, `$this_awardid` is only assigned a value if the `$_POST` value present (i.e. not empty), otherwise it's set to `null`; therefore:

```
if ($this_awardid) {
    // the value has something
} else {
    // the value is null
}
```

This works, because `!empty()` is essentially `isset($var) && $var == true`